# Multiple GCD request in a scrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView which i load images into while scrolling,and every time it has only 3 pages with images(current previous next ) .
It works great ,and the memory consumption is low (30-40M) for the iPad .

Problem is, that when i scroll fast(no paging enable), i get a memory warning, even that the memory is low.

I discovered that this is because of multiple GCD requests at once .
What can be done, in order to eliminate this from happen ?

One solution i could think of, is to start loading only when scroll view is decelerating , but i am afraid that the UX will be bad with this(now it looks great) ,

Another one, is using NSOperation for this- which is a higher level and might be better ?

Another one, is to use AutoreleasePool for the thread request-which i saw in a few articles.

What is the best approach for this ?

Here is the loader, that happens while scrolling (to relevant pages):

```
  [self downloadImageWithURL:userUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *tdata)
     {
         if (succeeded)
         {
               //load back
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                            {

                                UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:tdata scale:1];
                                if (image)
                                {
                                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
                                    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

                                    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                                 }


                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                               {

                                                   //LOAD EASY
                                                   [UIView transitionWithView:view
                                                                     duration:0.1f
                                                                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                                   animations:^
                                                    {
                                                         view.image=nil;
                                                        view.image=image;

                                                    }
                                                     completion:nil];

                                               });
                             image=nil;
                            });
         }
     }];


}
```

Comment: I discovered that this is because of multiple GCD requests at once - how did you find that out?

Comment: I just started a project and sent multiple requests at once, and could see that, vs , sending them with delay .

Comment: Why not just cancel requests that are not currently on screen or about to be seen?

Comment: because you can't cancel GCD requests.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution that works great for me, i have an array of all what is being loading right now, and i have checked when this array size causing troubles . When user scrolls i check its size, and when the size exceeded a certain size, i just stop the scroller from scrolling fast. This happens usually when the user is scrolling too fast.

```
CGRect frame=scroller.frame;
    frame.origin.y=scroller.contentOffset.y-1.0;
     if ([imagesAreLoading count]>10  )//too many requests has being made.
    [scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps other people.